# Interpretation of system services on iPhone [Arrows (hollow, purple and gray)]

Tags: iphone, privacy, services, geolocation

I use an iPhone 11 for work and I share my location with friends and family. I currently have the following results:

[image]

Can I safely conclude that in the last 24 hours no one has verified my location using the "Share my location" app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No icon means no location was requested in the last 24 hours by that item, providing the device wasn't factory reset such that the information was lost.

Comment: Thank you so much. I confirm that no information has been lost and that the device has not been reset. Everything is normal. On iPhone, are you aware of any other app that could track our location?

Comment: @Jacob Any third-party app granted "Always" access to your location could track you. You can review which apps you have granted location permission to on the previous page.